# Are there other means of obtaining the properties of a target in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have created a C++ static library, and in order to make it searchable easily, I create the following cmake files:

**lib.cmake**

```
# The installation prefix configured by this project.
set(_IMPORT_PREFIX "C:/------/install/win32")

# Create imported target boost
add_library(lib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "lib_define1;lib_define2"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/../include"
)
# Load information for each installed configuration.
get_filename_component(_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
file(GLOB CONFIG_FILES "${_DIR}/lib-*.cmake")
foreach(f ${CONFIG_FILES})
  include(${f})
endforeach()
```

**lib-debug.cmake**

```
# Import target "boost" for configuration "Debug"
set_property(TARGET lib APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS DEBUG)
set_target_properties(boost PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES_DEBUG "CXX"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/Debug/staticlib/lib.lib"
  )
```

When I want to use this library in an executable, I can simply invoke it by calling find_package command:

```
find_package(lib REQUIRED)
if(lib_FOUND)
     message("lib has been found")
else()
        message("lib cannot be found")
endif(boost_FOUND)
```

It works and if I want to know the head file directory of the library, I will have to call it this way:

```
  get_target_property(lib_dir lib INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

I was just wondering whether there are other ways of obtaining the properties of an target. In this case I expect some variable like `lib_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` will exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, CMake does not automatically define variables for the properties of a target (or of anything else). If you need the value of a property, you have to query it explicitly (using `get_property` or the specific getters like `get_target_property` etc.).

In your specific case, `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` is a property which I would expect you would *not* need to query at all. The whole point of `INTERFACE_*` properties is to propagate usage requirements automatically; their propagation is implemented in CMake itself.